# I want to convert month number to month name in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, json

This is the data in json file. the _id i am passing is month number.

```
Const incomes = [
    {
        "_id": 6,
        "total": 3000
    },
    {
        "_id": 7,
        "total": 3500
    }
]
```

I am trying to convert the month number to month name by using this function. but its not working.

```
  const monthNames = ["January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
  const data = useMemo(
    () => incomes.map((income, monthNames) => ({ ...income, name: monthNames[income._id.getMonth()] }
    )
    ), [incomes, monthNames]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this!
I think when you passed the monthNames in the .map it declared it as a new variable and that's why the result was undefined.
P.S. Added -1 to income._id so the months would match
Hope it helps :)

```
  const incomes = [
    {
        "_id": 6,
        "total": 3000
    },
    {
        "_id": 7,
        "total": 3500
    }
  ]

  const monthNames = ["January", "Feburary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

  const data = useMemo(
    () => incomes.map((income) => ({ ...income, name: monthNames[income._id -1]}
    )
    ), [incomes, monthNames]);
```